# Copy clipboard from Notepad++ to PuTTY issue

Tags: linux, python, notepad++, putty, ipython

I have code written in Notepad++ and PuTTY into a linux server. When copying multiple lines to ipython on the linux server, it only reads and executes one line and forgets the rest of the lines I copied.

I assumed it was EOL used but using them all(Windows, Unix, macintosh), ipython continues to read only the first line and forgets the rest.

Reason I don't just save the file, transfer, and run it is because I like to debug small blocks of code, so working in ipython is the most convenient for some issues. I don't want to keep copying line by line!